# elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error) error code=61

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana

In my python script, first I connected with elasticsearch through elasticSearch class, and I'm fetching data using search in es object;

it is throwing errors like:

```
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10654d420>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused))
```

I have tried:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
with open("cred.txt","r") as f:
    user,passw=f.readline().split("-")

es = Elasticsearch(['<hostname>:9200'], basic_auth=(user, passw))
doc1 = {
  "aggs": {
    "keys": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "kubernetes.container_name"
        , "size": 600
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
print(es.info)
res1 = es.search(index="<index-name>", body=doc1)
print(res1)
```

`print(es.info)` working fine but on line es.search throws error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/utils.py", line 414, in wrapped
    return api(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py", line 3770, in search
    return self.perform_request(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/_base.py", line 286, in perform_request
    meta, resp_body = self.transport.perform_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elastic_transport/_transport.py", line 329, in perform_request
    meta, raw_data = node.perform_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py", line 199, in perform_request
    raise err from None
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10654d420>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused))
```

Comment: Could you check from that server you can reach the elasticsaerch with curl?